# How to refer Lambda to std::function<void()>

Tags: c++11, lambda, threadpool

Iam building a threadpool to boost my raycaster performance.

Therefore my threadpool has a job queue:

```
std::vector<std::function<void()>> jobs;
```

and a public function to add jobs to the threadpool.

```
void ThreadPool::executeJob(std::function<void()> job)
{
  std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lockJobs(this->lockJobs);
  this->jobs.push_back(job);
}
```

The only function i want to refer to the threadpool since now is the following:

```
void MeshScene::CastRays(const Ray& ray, const int rayCount, const MatrixF& rot, 
                         std::vector<IntersectionResult>& rayCollection)
{
    // perform raycasts...
    rayCollection.push_back(intersectionResult);
  }
}
```

The `rayCollection` is a member of the class from which i call the `executeJob(std::function<void()> job)` function.

Now i try to refer it with lambda

```
threadPool.executeJob([ray, rayCount, rotation, this] () { CastRays(ray, rayCount, rotation, std::ref(this->testIntersectionCollection)); });
```

I get confusing errors and i think my lamdba expression doesn't make sense. Any ideas?

Or does somebody know a better solution instead of collecting jobs with std::function?

Comment: you're using `std::ref` wrong: it returns a reference **wrapper**, you probably only want `this->testIntersectionCollection`, it would help to see your error messages though

Comment: Please post the actual errors generated.  Yes, all of them.

Comment: While debugging for the last few hours i found some other errors in my threadpool. As soon as i fixed them i will post a full error list concerning this problem. What do you mean by all of them, is the callstack and the exception text enough or how can i copy all of the errors occuring?

Comment: Are they compile errors or runtime errors? If they're run-time errors, you'll have to give some more context. If compiler, show them all. BTW, the fact that I'm having to ask whether your errors are compile-time or run-time indicates an under-specified question.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for the missing response from my side. I figured out a solution but forgot to post it. But here is how i did it:

The Threadpool function:

```
void executeJob(std::function<void()> job);
```

The function to call:

```
void CastRays(std::vector<Result>* resultCollection)
```

The call from the Threadpool:

```
threadPool.executeJob([this] () { CastRays(&this->intersectionCollectionOne); });
```